# Display only current project's root folder in IntelliJ's changes window

Tags: mercurial, intellij-idea

All my projects are contained within the same (Mercurial) repository because these projects are rather small.
So I have this folder "Workspace" containing other folders "Project A", "Project B" and so on.
And the ".hg" folder.

In IntelliJ, the "changes window" shows all uncomitted changes from all projects. If I open "Project A", it displays also changes of "Project B" and vice versa.
But I just want to see those uncomitted changes of the current project's folder.

Is there any setting which could resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Changes view always shows all changes under the VCS roots associated with the project. You can use the "Group by Directory" button to separate the changes under Project A and Project B.